# Node.js Dockerfile Build fails with "COPY failed: no source files were specified" using Azure Pipelines but works locally

Tags: node.js, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to push a docker image for a node.js application to the azure container registry. Even though the docker build works locally, it is failing on the docker build task using Azure Pipelines with this error:

```
Starting: Build container image
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.201.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
docker build -f backend/Dockerfile acr_name.io/repo_name:latest /home/vsts/work/1/s
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/5a7f95db-4f1c-48b7-9a00-ef5a0d9fb6c6.sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.879MB

Step 1/13 : FROM node:lts-bullseye
lts-bullseye: Pulling from library/node
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:lts-bullseye
 ---> 9eeae0e42775
Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 053af9da5ccc
Removing intermediate container 053af9da5ccc
 ---> 20a650e0839d
Step 3/13 : COPY package*.json ./
COPY failed: no source files were specified
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-bullseye
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "./dist/main.js" ]
```

This is my pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: dockerFilePath
  type: string
- name: acrName
  type: string
- name: registryPath
  type: string
- name: azureSubscription
  type: string
- name: workingdirectory
  type: string
  default: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)

steps: 
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Login to Azure Container Registry
  inputs:
    azureSubscription:  ${{ parameters.azureSubscription }}
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az acr login -n ${{ parameters.acrName }}'
    displayName: Login to ACR
    
- bash: |
    docker build -f ${{ parameters.dockerFilePath }} -t ${{ parameters.registryPath }}:latest ${{ parameters.workingdirectory }}
  displayName: Build container image
```

package-lock.json and package.json are in the same folder as the Dockerfile.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `COPY` is not able to copy files. Either they don't exist or it is a permission issue. I'd guess on the former. You could try and do a `echo "${{ parameters.workingdirectory }}"` and `ls ${{ parameters.workingdirectory }}`  to see what the value of the workingdirectory parameter and the content of the folder is. If you have checked out multiple repositories, then "workingdirectory" could point to a different folder.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that the working directory was wrong...

Comment: Yeah that's usaly the case. Don't forget to create an answer to your question and accept it.